# jspm install npm:fb cannot find crypto

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, jspm

I use jspm to intall `npm:fb`, and use in my js, but I get

> GET /jspm_packages/npm/crypto@0.0.3.js 404

my step:

> jspm init
>
> jspm install npm:fb

Should I add something to fix it?

My `index.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>try fb</title>
</head>
<body>
  <script src="jspm_packages/system.js"></script>
  <script src="config.js"></script>
  <script>
    System.import('lib/main.js')
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My `lib/main.js`

```
import fb from 'fb'

export default {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As jspm says during the installation of fb:

```
warn Main entry point not found for npm:crypto@0.0.3.
     Adjust this property in the package.json or with an override, setting "main": false if this is the intention.
```

So you can add the following override to your package.json:

```
"overrides": {
  "npm:crypto@0.0.3": {
     "main": "md5.js"
   }
}
```

This chooses one of two files of the crypto module as main. This fixes the original problem. But you will get another one:

`Node tls module not supported in browsers.`

So I believe you need to find a browser-friendly version of fb.